# Replacing my hdd with ssd and placing hdd in odd drive bay

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

Hey guys i am thinking to upgrade to an ssd by removing my hdd and placing the ssd in place of the hdd and placing the hdd in the odd drive bay using a hdd caddy. Now the problem is that the odd sata port is of 1.5 gbps and i dont know how much speed will be actually good for my hdd. Will it degrade the performance of my hdd cause i will be storing games on it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can plug your HDD in your 1.5Gb/s port and it will run just fine since SATA is backwards compatible, but the speed of the drive will be limited to this 1.5Gb/s. In other words, if you install a SATA III 6Gb/s drive in a system that only supports SATA I 1.5Gb/s, then the performance will be limited to SATA I 1.5Gb/s levels.

Hope this helps and cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

That's ugly. It won't hurt anything, the drive will just run at that speed. If you have an expansion port add one of these. 6gbps is probably what a your new drive supports. [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816124065&cm_re=sata_controller_6_gb-*-16-124-065-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816124065&cm_re=sata_controller_6_gb-_-16-124-065-_-Product)

Comment: no i dont have an expansion port on my lappy and i dont think you quite got my question, i meant that will connecting my hdd to a 1.5 gbps sata will make some difference coz i have heard that hdd's dont go up to that speed.

Comment: I understood perfectly well. So it's a laptop. Install the ssd. If you look at it, it'll probably say 6 gbps on the label. The interface you have, as mentioned in your question is 1.5gbps. All SATA hard drives are backward compatible. This means that it will "run at that speed" (SATA I (1.5 gbps)).

Comment: i am talking about hdd on Sata I (1.5 gbps) not my ssd, i will placing my ssd on a 6 gbps and my hdd on 1.5 gbps, i just want to know that will my hdd run slower on 1.5 gbps cause i have read that anyways an hdd cannot go that high

Comment: Depends on the model. The cache can certainly make user of higher transfer speeds.